# Squid SSL intercept works for most google sites but not www.google.com

Tags: ssl, squid

I am able to access pretty much all of Google's .co.uk services now that I have configured squid to use SSL.  I can also view my certificate information in the certificate being presented by Google.  However, if I navigate to www.google.com, I get a ERR_CERT_INVALID being reported by Chrome.  Why does it work for some but not others?

Comment: Use Google (without SSL bump thiugh) to find and answer - this has been discussed in the `squid-users` mailing list. No solution though as of now.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome treats `google.com` and some related domains specially. As mentioned in its [Root Certificate Policy](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy):

> Chrome has extra checks built in for accessing Google sites, and displayed a warning to the user.

SSL bump is *supposed* to work properly if you have imported Squid's CA certificate into Google Chrome or the operating system's store. On Windows, certificates should be imported into [Trusted Root Certification Authorities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx); there are [special instructions for the Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3504942?hl=en).

If this *doesn't* work, you have probably run into a bug in Google Chrome, but you should double check that squid's root certificate was imported correctly.

Comment: My guess is it's a bug.  I had imported the cert into both the Windows (system) trusted store and Chrome, via the cert manager built into Chrome.